# Soft keyboard isn't shown automatically when swiped viewpager android

Tags: android, fragment

I have a viewpager with 2 pages. In page 2, i have 6 Editexts to input text. i want to show the sortkeyboard when i switch to page 2. I tried many solutions but it didnt work for me.

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@color/background_splash"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/logo_height_primary"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/logo_height_primary"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/tip_enter_otp"
        android:textColor="#222222"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnOtp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Editext
            android:id="@+id/edtOTP1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edt_otp_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_otp_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_otp_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edt_otp_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/background_textbox_otp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Editext
            android:id="@+id/edtOTP2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edt_otp_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_otp_size"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_otp_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edt_otp_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/background_textbox_otp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Editext
            android:id="@+id/edtOTP3"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edt_otp_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_otp_size"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_otp_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edt_otp_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/background_textbox_otp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Editext
            android:id="@+id/edtOTP4"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edt_otp_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_otp_size"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_otp_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edt_otp_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/background_textbox_otp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Editext
            android:id="@+id/edtOTP5"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edt_otp_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_otp_size"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_otp_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edt_otp_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/background_textbox_otp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Editext
            android:id="@+id/edtOTP6"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edt_otp_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_otp_size"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_otp_padding"
            android:background="@drawable/background_textbox_otp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you guys

Comment: which solutions you did tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code for opening the keyboard. You can add this code inside `onTabSelected`method

```
 InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(
linearLayout.getApplicationWindowToken(),
InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this attributes in your layout tag in XML file:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

it doesn't works on ScrollView therefore you need to add these attributes to the main child of ScrollView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@color/background_splash"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/logo_height_primary"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/logo_height_primary"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/tip_enter_otp"
        android:textColor="#222222"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnOtp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Editext
            android:id="@+id/edtOTP1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edt_otp_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_otp_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_otp_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edt_otp_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/background_textbox_otp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Editext
            android:id="@+id/edtOTP2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edt_otp_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_otp_size"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_otp_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edt_otp_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/background_textbox_otp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Editext
            android:id="@+id/edtOTP3"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edt_otp_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_otp_size"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_otp_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edt_otp_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/background_textbox_otp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Editext
            android:id="@+id/edtOTP4"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edt_otp_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_otp_size"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_otp_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edt_otp_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/background_textbox_otp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Editext
            android:id="@+id/edtOTP5"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edt_otp_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_otp_size"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_otp_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edt_otp_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/background_textbox_otp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Editext
            android:id="@+id/edtOTP6"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edt_otp_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_otp_size"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_otp_padding"
            android:background="@drawable/background_textbox_otp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **windowSoftInputMode** in your activity in manifest like this

```
<activity
         android:name=".YourActivity"
         android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"></activity>
```